# Mysql Server running but Artisan in Laravel project doesn't think so

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, artisan-migrate

So, I have recently installed Mysql Server in my Macbook (Mac OS 10.11) and I also installed Mysql Workbench and it works great!

The problem comes when I want to migrate form a Laravel Project using Php Artisan, every time I run the `php artisan migrate` command it return the following error

```
  [PDOException]                                    
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I also noticed I have to mysql installations i the following paths:

```
/usr/local/mysql
/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.11-x86_64/ (this is the one I am using)
```

I placed in the .bash_profile a PATH to the new one (5.7.13) like this:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/mysql-5.7.13-osx10.11-x86_64/bin/
```

Do you guys know how can I fix this? Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Path to the binary doesn't matter, in this case it's looking for a MySQL socket file.

1. Find your socket file (`find / -name mysql.sock`)
2. Ensure this path is set in my.cnf used by your PHP (you can run `php -i |grep pdo_mysql.default_socket` to see the default path)
3. As a workaround, you could set a symbolic link from 1 to 2 (eg. `ln -s /usr/local/mysql/var/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock`) but ideally you want to set a correct path for PDO (or whatever MySQL extension you are using for PHP)